# Mapping List<T> inside class to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework, sqlite, poco

So my underlying data structure was a .json file. I am in the stages of changing this to a `sqlite` database.

In one of my normal POCO objects, I have a list of a different class type.

E.g:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public List<Colors> lstColors {get;set;}
}

public class Colors
{
    public string some_member {get;set}
}
```

What I'm finding difficult is mapping the `lstColors` to a single table in sqlite. I was thinking when I use Entity Framework, it would automatically be able to do this for me somehow?

I'm not sure how Code-First would work in this particular situation. Ideally I'd want the database built directly from the above class structure.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible

Comment: How exactly would I achieve this?

Comment: You said it is difficult is mapping the lstColors to a single table in sqlite. So, pls tell more details about what is the difficult in your question first